# How to bypass cloudflare/datadome with undetected_chromedriver not able to bypass it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare

Im trying to skip cloudflare/datadome with undetected_chromedriver but ended up with their captcha page

tried with proxy as well and add other chrome options to look like a normal browser

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
script = "Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => false})"
driver = uc.Chrome(
    options=chrome_options,
    seleniumwire_options=proxy_options
)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {"source": script})

driver.get('https://www.dischem.co.za/')
```